# constexpr member function in template class in c++

Tags: c++11

I have a few classes to describe some shapes.

### Line.hpp

```
class Line {
private:
    double _x;
public:
    Line(double x) : _x(x) { }
    virtual std::size_t size() const { return 1; }
};
```

### Quad.hpp

```
class Quad : public Line {
private:
    double _y;
public:
    Quad(double y) : _y(y) { }
    virtual std::size_t size() const { return 2; }
};
```

### Hexa.hpp

```
class Hexa final : public Quad {
private:
    double _z;
public:
    Hexa(double z) : _z(z) { }
    std::size_t size() const { return 3; }
};
```

My shapes are used by shape workers.

```
class Quad_Worker : public Worker<Quad> {
    // Implements Worker::do_something.
    do_something(Quad some_shape) const;
};
template<class Shape>
class Worker {
    virtual do_something(Shape some_shape) const = 0;
};
```

I want to use the size of the shape to create a fixed (at compile time) array. How can I use the function `size()` as a `constexpr`? I tried converting the constructors to `constexpr`, but that does not work because the destructors of `Line` and `Quad` are virtual.

Should I use a static member method or variable instead?

I'm using C++11.

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you simply store the `static constexpr size_t` for each shape in a dedicated class? Is it a requirement for an assignment?

Comment: I was trying to figure out if there was a better way to declare the size. I thought of static constexpr size_t, but then I was thrown off by the fact that each class has to have this variable, which seemed repetitive.

This is not for an assignment. The code here is a simplification of a larger project dealing with numerical simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put something like this in each class:

```
enum { static_size = 1 };
```

Obviously it will be a different number depending on the class, but the same name.  Then you can use `Shape::static_size` in `Worker`.

I chose the particular name `static_size` and the `enum` type to mirror `boost::array`, but if you don't care about that you could also say:

```
static constexpr size_t const_size = 1;
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid having to declare static_size or const_size in each class?

Comment: No, unless you want to make an otherwise-useless base class like `template <size_t Size> struct SizedThing { enum { static_size = Size }; };` and inherit from `SizedThing<1>` instead...but that's just more complicated, not better.